# Python: Accessing inside a function from another function

Tags: python, function, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to access an entry inside a function from another function. But it tells me it's not defined. I've been researching a lot, but I can't seem to find anything that helps me.

This is my code, I have been shortening it down to make it easier for you guys. Though it should be enough to give you the idea.

```
from tkinter import*

class hunterClass:

    def BMHunter():
        hunter = Tk()
        hunter.title("Beast Mastery Gear Worth Calculator")

        agiString = StringVar()

        agiText = Label(hunter, text = "Input points of agility:").grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        agiEntry = Entry(hunter, textvariable = agiString).grid(row = 3, column = 1)

        calculate = Button(hunter, text = "Calculate", command = hunterClass.calculateFun).grid(row = 12, column = 1)

    def calculateFun():
        agiF = float(agiEntry.get())

window = Tk()
window.title("Gear Worth Calculator")

hunterText = Label(window, text = "Hunter").grid(row = 3, column = 0)
hunterBM = Button(window, text = "Beast Mastery", width = 12, command = hunterClass.BMHunter).grid(row = 4, column = 0)
```

Comment: Please learn how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It would be cool to clarify which variable has not been declared. But in the end i am sure you can solve this question by using the global keyword.

Comment: This example might be helpful: https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example

Comment: You seem to define static methods as you never create an instance of your class, and never pass `self`. If this is what you want, then make your methods static by putting `@staticmethod` in a line before each `def`

Comment: is self.variable not an option : https://gist.github.com/vi3k6i5/3f2091c37e30788b60b690808774bd3a Try this if class members are ok with you.

Comment: What background in programming do you have? Generally when you declare a variable inside a function it is only defined inside that function. on the other hand I think you are trying to use _instance variables_ which varies in notation from language to language, maybe take a look at [the documentation on classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) to get a better idea of how to do it in python.

Answer (score 0):

you need another indent in `def BMHunter` to define `calculateFun`

I assume you are trying to use closures in python:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure

So

```
def BMHunter():
    ....
    def calculateFun()
```

Your current code is taking `calculateFun` to be another function of the same class and not local function inside `BMHunter`

I'd also recommend defining the function as def `BMHunter(self)` unless you deliberately want to make it static/class method

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found out making the variables globals worked.